# Proof of cardinality of fibres - why finiteness condition?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907081/cardinality-of-fibres-of-covering-maps-of-connected-spaces) in showing that cardinality of fibers of $B$ are the same, it is assumed $k$ is finite. Is this necessary?

We can just fix $b_0 \in B$, and consider set, 
$A:= \{ b \in B  : |p^{-1}(b)|=|p^{-1}(b_0)| \}$. The proofs follows exactly the same.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes any cardinal $k$ should work.