# A problem about covering space in Munkres. Why the elements in the neighborhood can only has exactly $k$ preimages.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

[image]

When I tried to deal with this problem, I defined 2 sets $$\begin{align*}
C= \left\{ b \in   B: |p^{-1}(b)| =k \right\}
\\ D= \left\{ b \in   B : |p^{-1}(b)|  \neq k \right\}
\end{align*}$$ Since $b_{0} \in C$ , so $C \neq \emptyset$ . Then I assume $D \neq \emptyset$, I want to find a contradiction by using $B$ is connected to prove $D$ is indeed empty.

I need to prove $C$ is open. I consider any $b \in C$. Suppose $p^{-1}(b)=\left\{ e_{1},\cdots,e_{k} \right\}$ are in $E$ . Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ such that $$\begin{align*}
p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{n=1}^{k} V_{k}
\end{align*}$$ Since $p \bigg|_{V_{n}}$ is homeomorphism, this ensures that there must be $k$ open sets $V_{k}$ which are mapped onto $U$.

Then, I want to prove that for each $b' \in U$ , $p^{-1}(b')$ still has exact $k$ preimages, and then we will have $$\begin{align*}
U \subset C
\end{align*}$$ which proves $C$ is open. However, I think that $b'$ must at least have $k$ preimages brought by $V_{1},\cdots, V_{k}$, but I can't say why it has exact $k$ preimages.

Suppose $|p^{-1}(b')|=k+1$, what will lead to a contradiction? I think the contradiction may relate to $b$ having exact $k$ preimages. Any help? Thanks.

---

Edit:
[image]

I'm wondering why the situation above won't happen. That is, there exists a $e_{k+1}'$ such that $$\begin{align*}
p(e_{k+1}') = b'
\end{align*}$$ which leads to $p^{-1}(b')$ has preimages more than $k$

Comment: You can prove $C$ is clopen, which avoids contradiction entirely. Your proof starts right. You can find the rest of the proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/907668/269764

Comment: The essence is that we get homeomorphisms on each $V_i$, and homeos preserve cardinality being bijections so each point in $U$ has exactly $k$ preimages so $b$ will be an interior point.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen Thanks, but I am still confused. I edited my question to be more clear. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Look at what you wrote again. There are only $k$ preimages under $p$ of $U$, namely the $V_i$. Remember that $p^{-1}(U)$ is, by definition, the union of all the $p^{-1}(b')$ for all $b'  \in U$. As such, you've already excluded the case you seem concerned about purely by definition: the preimages of each point must lie in the union of the $V_i$ by definition, so you can't have a preimage in some other set $V$. There also can't be more than one preimage per $V_i$ because we get local homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it is not properly elaborated. You consider $b \in C$, but you should not write $p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{n=1}^k V_n$ because this *presupposes* that there are $k$ sheets over $U$.

All we know is that each point of $B$ has an evenly covered open neigborhood $U \subset B$ which means that
$$p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha \tag{1}$$
with pairwise disjoint open $V_\alpha \subset E$ which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$. Let $p_\alpha : V_\alpha \to U$ denote the homeomorphism obtained by restricting $p$.

Given $x \in U$, the fiber $p^{-1}(x)$ has the form

$$p^{-1}(x) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x) . \tag{2}$$

This formula seems to be the core issue in your question, so let us prove it
carefully. Obviously each  $p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x) \subset p^{-1}(x)$ since $p_{\alpha}$ is the restriction of $p$ to $V_\alpha$. Hence $p^{-1}(x) \supset \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$. Conversely, let $y \in p^{-1}(x)$ (which means $p(y) = x)$. Since $p^{-1}(x) \subset p^{-1}(U)$,  $(1)$ shows that there exists a unique $\alpha \in A$ such that $y \in V_\alpha$. We conclude $p_\alpha(y) = p(y) = x$, thus $y \in p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$. This shows $p^{-1}(x) \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$.

Since each $p_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism, each $E_{x,\alpha} = p_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$ is a one-point subset of $V_\alpha$. The $E_{x,\alpha}$ are pairwise disjoint (because the $V_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint), therefore the cardinality of $p^{-1}(x)$ has the same value  $\lvert A \rvert$ for all $x \in U$.

But we know that the cardinality of $p^{-1}(b)$ with $b \in C$ is $k$, thus for all $x \in U$ the cardinality of $p^{-1}(x)$ is $k$. This proves $U \subset C$.

That $D$ is open is proved by the same argument. If $b \in D$, then $p^{-1}(b)$ has a cardinality $\aleph \ne k$ and thus all fibers $p^{-1}(x)$, where $x$ lies in an evenly covered open neighborhood $U$, have cardinality $\aleph \ne k$. Hence $U \subset D$.